# Java Permutation Assignment

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, permutation

Main class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class PermutationGenerator{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random bruh = new Random();

        List<Integer> filledArray = nextPermutation.fillArray();

        int[] randomArray = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
            int randomPosition = bruh.nextInt(10 - i) + 1;
            randomArray[i] = filledArray.get(randomPosition);
            filledArray.remove(randomPosition);
        }

        System.out.print("List 1: ");
        printArray(randomArray);

    }

        public static void printArray(int[] array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }


        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Runner Class: 
`import java.util.ArrayList;

public class nextPermutation {

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> fillArray() {
        ArrayList<Integer> randomArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        randomArray.add(0);
        randomArray.add(1);
        randomArray.add(2);
        randomArray.add(3);
        randomArray.add(4);
        randomArray.add(5);
        randomArray.add(6);
        randomArray.add(7);
        randomArray.add(8);
        randomArray.add(9);
        randomArray.add(10);



        return randomArray;

    }
```

}
`

I'm supposed to print out something like this:

List  1:   4  6  8  1  9  7 10  5  3  2

List  2:   6  8  1  7  3  4  9 10  5  2

List  3:   2  4  9  6  8  1 10  5  7  3

List  4:   8  5  4  3  2  9  6  7  1 10

List  5:  10  3  2  6  8  9  5  7  4  1

List  6:   9 10  3  2  1  5  6  8  4  7

List  7:   3  8  5  9  4  2 10  1  6  7

List  8:   3  2  4  5  7  6  9  8 10  1

List  9:   4  1  5 10  8  3  6  2  7  9

List 10:   3  5  2  4  1  7  9  6  8 10

But for me, it only prints out one line. 
I think I can use a for loop in order to do this. Alternatively, I could just brute force it but I prefer the former.

What I need help on is where and how I should start the for loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you do not have 10 lists, you only have one.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware. Did you read the question?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` is a loop that runs 10 times. but during each loop it prints 1 number and a space. If you want 10 lists you need to run that for loop 9 more times

Comment: I guess you are aware that there are more than 10 Permutations

Answer (score 0):

a lot cleaner to simply use `Collections::shuffle`

```
    List<Integer> filledArray = fillArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Collections.shuffle(filledArray);
        System.out.println(filledArray);
    }
```

**output**

```
[7, 0, 3, 5, 2, 1, 9, 10, 4, 8, 6]
[3, 7, 6, 0, 1, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 10]
[3, 7, 2, 4, 9, 10, 0, 8, 5, 1, 6]
[8, 1, 0, 7, 4, 2, 3, 6, 10, 9, 5]
[2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 10, 9, 1, 6, 7, 0]
[10, 2, 0, 1, 5, 8, 7, 6, 9, 3, 4]
[1, 5, 0, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 7, 3]
[2, 8, 1, 9, 7, 3, 5, 6, 10, 4, 0]
[9, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 3, 10, 5, 7]
[4, 5, 2, 3, 10, 9, 6, 8, 0, 1, 7]
```

Comment: I think it's better to have the declaration of `filledArray` and `randomArray` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simply I defined your part of your code in a method `mixArray()`

Then I added a for loop that runs 10 times to print 10 lists.

The for loop in `printArray` does run 10 times but it prints 1 number and a space during 
each loop so that's why you were getting just 1 line at the end.

```
    for (int p = 1; p <= 10; p++) {
        mixArray();
        System.out.print("List "+p+": ");
        printArray(randomArray);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void mixArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
            int randomPosition = bruh.nextInt(10 - i) + 1;
            randomArray[i] = filledArray.get(randomPosition);
            filledArray.remove(randomPosition);
        }
    }
```

Also you might wanna keep in mind that your randomizing the array method might give you back a duplicate array. The chances are very low but it is possible.